# Finding $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1 + \sin(\theta)}\;d\theta$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

In Stewart's Calculus book (7th edition) on page 692 there is example 4. Here one ends up having to find
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1 + \sin(\theta)}\;d\theta.
$$
Stewart says that one can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1 - \sin(\theta)}$, but I don't understand how one can do this since $\sqrt{1 -\sin(\theta)}$ is zero when $\theta = \pi/2$.

> My question is therefore, how to properly calculate the above integral.

My only thought is to somehow change the integral so that one avoids the point of $\pi/2$ where $1-\sin(\theta) =0$, but the integral is still going to be over a interval of length $2\pi$.

Comment: There is an eigth edition?

Comment: @LearningMath: Oops, I meant the 7th edition...

Comment: You can break up the integral to 0~pi/2 and pi/2~2pi, and leave pi/2 as a removable discontinuity. Integral does not care about such discontinuity.

Comment: @insignia: Does this not give an improper integral then?

Comment: The function does not diverge, so it is not an improper integral, if my definition of improper integral is correct.

Comment: Stewart defines an improper integral to be any integral involving an infinity, either in limit, or having infinite discontinuities.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I think that the definition on page 547 would include the function being discontinuous at an endpoint of an interval.

Comment: since the discontinuity is removable, you may as well define the value there as the limit there, making the function continuous. You can then proceed integrating as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1 + \sin(\theta)}\;d\theta.
$$

Let: $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1 + \sin(\theta)}\;d\theta=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right)}\;-du=\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right)}\;du
$$
$$
=\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + \cos{u}}\;du
$$

Finally use:

$$\cos^2 u = \frac{1 + \cos 2u}{2}$$

To finish the job

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, by multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{1 - \sin\theta}$, you're introducing a removable discontinuity at the point $\theta = \pi/2$. It turns out that integrating the function $f(\theta) = \sqrt{1-\sin\theta}$, or the function $g(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - \sin\theta}$  with restricted domain $\theta \neq \pi/2$, will yield the exact same results.

As you've pointed out, you could show this by computing the integral

$$\lim_{b \to \pi/2^-} \left(\int_0^b f(\theta)\ d\theta\right) + \lim_{c \to \pi/2^+} \left(\int_c^{2\pi} f(\theta)\ d\theta\right),$$

and compare this to what you get paying no attention to the discontinuity at $\theta = \pi/2$.

More generally, if you ever study real analysis with measure theory, you'll learn that the set $\{\pi/2\}$ has measure zero on the real line, and throwing away any measure zero set from the domain of a function doesn't change the value of any integrals. Something tells me you just may go on to do this, if you're paying such close of attention to a calculus text.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}I&=&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}+\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}\right)\,d\theta\\&=&2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sqrt{1+\sin\theta}+\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}\right)\,d\theta=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\&=&2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\right)\,dt=2\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}=\color{red}{4\sqrt{2}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would think about it. The $\dfrac{\sqrt{1 - \sin \theta}}{\sqrt{1 - \sin \theta}}$ term behaves as it should (as a constant factor of $1$) everywhere except for the exact point $\pi/2$. The integral at the exact point $\pi/2$ has no effect on the value of the integral as a whole (in fact, an integral over any set with measure zero gives an integral equal to zero).